# postgresql is running but executing makemigrations throws an error that it is not running

Tags: python, postgresql

I installed postgresql 14 on my windows 11. Set it up to run on port 5432 (the default one).

Completed the installation but when I try to run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` it throws an error saying:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I checked in services and postgresql is running.

I ran the `\conninfo` command and here are the results of that command:

[image: \conninfo result]

Here is what my pgAdmin looks like

[image: pgAdmin]

I'm running the script using venv. Here is the settings.py page script

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'bidgala',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Abhi1331',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1'
    }
}
```

I looked for many solutions like restarting the service and such but didn't workout for me.

I could really use some help here!!.

Comment: Where are you running the `makemigrations` script; on the same machine, in a VM or virtual env, remotely? Add answer as update to question.

Comment: i updated the question accordingly. please take a look

Comment: Is the `venv` on the same machine? In the `venv` can you connect using `psql`? Also what happens if you use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`? Update question with answers.

Comment: Yes the ```venv``` is on the same machine. To the second question you asked, im not so sure how to connect using ```venv```. The same error happens with localhost as well.

Comment: Assuming `venv` means a Python virtual environment, activate it and at the command line use `psql`. If `venv` means something else you will need to provide more information.

Comment: yes I did activate ```venv``` using  ```source ./venv/bin/activate```. I installed gui version of postgresql, it got installed in C drive. I can run/stop postgres from services.msc

Comment: There is no GUI version of Postgres. The GUI you are referring to is `pgAdmin` which is just a client like `psql`, it is not the Postgres server. Your issue seems to indicate that wherever you are running `makemigrations` is on a different network then the rest of the machine. In other words in some sort of virtual machine. Are you running  [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)?

Comment: Yes, i am using WSL, do i need to install postgres server in wsl?

Comment: Or instead of using wsl, would it work if i used python to create a venv?

Comment: I asked at the beginning if you where running in a VM, it would have been helpful to indicate that you where using WSL at that point. What you need to do is find what IP the Postgres server is being run on the host as seen by the WSL and use that instead of `localhost/127.0.0.`. Moving the Postgres server to the WSL just changes the problem to connecting from the host(Windows) to the guest(WSL).